# Cannot find match in string although there should be

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a kind of weird issue:
I've got byte data coming from a serial port.
I decode it with:

```
data.decode("utf8","backslashreplace")
```

The output looks like this:

```
\xf028B       |\x80 10:00p@ @+\x81   :0000
```

Just as I want it.
But when I filter for the regular expression (works fine on regexr.com)

```
data = re.search('(?<=\\x80).{10}?',data)
```

It just won't find any matches. The output is "None".

Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops. Let me correct that. I did exactly as you write. But I don't even get to use .group() because there's obviously no match.

Comment: it seems to work? https://repl.it/@downshift/WaterloggedGhostwhiteAdministrators I can't reproduce your results. Modify the code in the link to reproduce your results if you want so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: 10:00p@ @
Exactly what comes up in the simulation.
I just noticed it is using Python 3.6 while I use 3.7

Answer (score 1):

With your code it produces your expected results. Compare with:

```
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import re
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.0 (default, Aug 22 2018, 20:50:05) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
>>> data = '\xf028B       |\x80 10:00p@ @+\x81   :0000'
>>> pattern = '(?<=\\x80).{10}?'
>>> print(re.search(pattern, data).group())
 10:00p@ @
>>>
```

screencap:
[image: screencap]
 <s>Maybe it makes a difference if you are running Python3.7 Windows?</s>

Update: Also works with Python3.7.0 running on Windows 10 64-bit:

```
(53734290) C:\Users\daedw\Stackoverflow\53734290>Scripts\python.exe
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import re
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> data = '\xf028B       |\x80 10:00p@ @+\x81   :0000'
>>> pattern = '(?<=\\x80).{10}?'
>>> print(re.search(pattern, data).group())
 10:00p@ @
>>>
```

windows screencap:
[image]

Comment: Yes, as you did it it works just fine, however you did not consider the fact I convert the string from the bytes before. That conversion seems to make the difference
https://repl.it/repls/CalculatingTornAssignments

Comment: Since you decoded the bytes back to string using `"backslashreplace"` , the pattern won't match the resulting string on `'\\'`, why not remove it and use `pattern = '(?<=x80).{10}?'`? unless I'm still not considering something, it appears to work: https://repl.it/@downshift/RelievedSilkySeptagon

Comment: Interesting. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, let me know and I'll consider deleting this answer or hopefully someone can provide a correct answer

Comment: You were absolutely right. Just using x80 worked. Thanks alot!